# jqGrid select values from db with stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, jqgrid

I'm working on a website containing a jqGrid.

Im selecting the values from database with an sql statement like this :

`$grid->SelectCommand = 'Select id,name from users';`,

I tried to change the statement to stored procedure like this :

`$grid->SelectCommand = 'CALL getUsers()';`

but i discovered that this is impossible, however i googled alot, and couldnt find any example related with jqGrid with stored procedure. I was just wondering if that was possible ?Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get **SQL** rows from a stored procedure and load the data into the **jqGrid**, you need to configure your jqGrid JavaScript control by pointing its `url` property to the PHP file action, which will provide the **JSON** data.

In the PHP file, you call the stored procedure `$result = mysql_query("select getUsers()");`. And then you convert your SQL data to JSON object with the PHP function `json_encode`

Check the below example link for that:

> http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html > Items: Loading Data >
>   JSON Data

And, jqGrid - The HTML:

> http://www.secondpersonplural.ca/jqgriddocs/_2eb0ez973.htm (extracted
>   from wbp.us.edu.pl/js/jqgrid/jqgriddocs.pdf)

, for more information.

Comment: ill let u know the result when i get back to this problem :) thanks